# Break from for loop back into if statement vba

Tags: vba, loops, if-statement, for-loop, exit

I am trying to perform an action that will see if the date in range (dateRng) is less than today's date, and then, if it is, perform the for loop to hide the rows w.here a value in the column is zero. (I am paying off loans, and every month I want it to hide any loans that have been paid off.) Months are across columns, loans are in rows. Loan balance is (i, j).

The problem is that it never exits the for loop to go back and check the date after every new 'j' (column). It just stays in the for loop. I have tried break, exit, continue, etc. None seem to work, at least where I place them. How do I get it to check for the date, compare to 'today', THEN run the for loop to check each cell in the column, before moving on to column 2, checking the date and performing the same for loop.

It would be good to have it be dynamic, but that is not necessary, as every month I could just change the ranges in the code. This is strictly for my personal use. Any help is appreciated. thank you.

```
Sub hidePaid()

Dim day As Range, loanRng As Range, loanSum As Worksheet, dateRng As Range, cel2 As Range, i As Long, j As Long, col As Range

Set loanSum = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Loan Sum")
loanSum.Activate

Set dateRng = ActiveSheet.Range("D2:R2")
Set loanRng = ActiveSheet.Range("D4:R16")

For Each day In dateRng

If day.Value < Date Then

    For j = 1 To loanRng.Columns.Count
    For i = 1 To loanRng.Rows.Count

        If loanRng.Cells(i, j).Value < 1 Then
               loanRng.Cells(i, j).EntireRow.Hidden = True
        End If

    Next i
    Next j



End If

Next
End sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added comments in the code to show my changes.

You were close, but had one to many loops and like you say, needed to find the right place for the exit.

```
Sub hidePaid()
Dim day     As Range
Dim loanRng As Range
Dim loanSum As Worksheet
Dim dateRng As Range
Dim i       As Long

Set loanSum = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Loan Sum")
loanSum.Activate

Set dateRng = ActiveSheet.Range("D2:R2")
Set loanRng = ActiveSheet.Range("D4:R16")

'This loop processes by column
For Each day In dateRng

    'Once the date in the column is greater than today, it will stop processing
    'It assumes the values in dateRng are valid dates
    '(I.e. '01/01/2016' not just 'Jan', you can use number format in Excel to
    'get a date to show as 'Jan' if that is better for you)
    If DateDiff("d", Now(), day.Value) > 0 Then Exit For

    'The line of code you had should have worked in sense,
    'it would have touched every column but only procesed those before today
    'It also assumes that value in the cell to be an actual date
    'If day.Value < Date Then

    'You do not need a column loop here as you are already in one in the
    'previous loop
    'For j = 1 To loanRng.Columns.Count

    'This loop processes all the rows that are not already hidden and if
    'the value is equal to 0 then it hides the row
    'Note: you had the check to be less than 1, .50 is less than 1 and you don't
    'want to get caught out on a loan!
    For i = 1 To loanRng.Rows.Count

        If (loanRng.Cells(i, day.Column - 3).Value = 0) And (loanRng.Cells(i, day.Column - 3).EntireRow.Hidden = False) Then
            loanRng.Cells(i, day.Column - 3).EntireRow.Hidden = True
        End If

    Next i

Next

'Its good practice to clear out resources when finishing
Set dateRng = Nothing
Set loanRng = Nothing
Set loanSum = Nothing

End Sub
```